# Projection on index is an open map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $s_j: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, $(x_1,...,x_{j-1},x_j,x_{j+1},...,x_n)\mapsto(x_1,...,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},...,x_n)$.

> Is $s_j$ an open map?

My thoughts are: given a permutation $\sigma$ of the variables I can write $ (x_1,...,x_{j-1},x_j,x_{j+1},...,x_n)\mapsto^{\sigma}(x_1,...,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},...,x_n,x_j)\mapsto^{\pi_{n+1}}(x_1,...,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},...,x_n) $, so that $s_j=\pi_j\circ\sigma$.

Being $\sigma$ linear and invertible it is open, and hopefully $\pi_j$ is open, so my claim would follow.

$\pi_j$ could be open as I may see it as the projection on the first factor in the product space $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It’s not necessary to consider a permutation, just take the counter image wrt $s_j$ of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and show it’s open.

Comment: **HINT**: Notice that $s_j(B_{\mathbb{R}^n}(x, \epsilon)) = B_{\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}}(s_j(x), \epsilon)$ and image preserves union, and represent any open set as a union of open balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb R^{n-1}$ can be viewed as a quotient space of $\Bbb R^n$ due to the map you defined. 
Now use the fact that a set in a quotient space is open if and only if its preimage under the projection map is open.

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to show $s_j$ is open on a base for $\Bbb R^n$ and this is obvious as

$$s_j[\prod_{i=1}^n O_i]=\prod_{i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus \{j\}} O_i$$

so it sends basic open sets to basic open sets.